# If function successful, then repeat function - PHP

Tags: php, function

I have the following function to upload a file to a database table field.

```
protected function _upload_file() {
  ...
}
```

Once uploaded, uploading a new file overwrites the original uploaded file.

What I want is to establish a new upload without overwriting the file. The way I see it, I would have to create a new function like;

```
function if_upload_file() {
   ...
}
```

If that function is successful, then repeat function.

Any idea how I could accomplish that?

Comment: are you storing files in db? can you post some codes.

Comment: The files aren't stored in the database. A crud application reads the table and stores values for data paths in the respective field, which it then interprets and links to it's default upload folder.

Comment: To the moderators: As I understand it, Stack Overflow is for developers and programmers to find answers for their programming-related problems. As I see it, I asked a relevant question, I got a relevant answer. Seeing that I got the answer to my problem with the amount of information provided, I see absolutely no reason why this question should be marked as off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the function return true if the file was uploaded successfully and as long as it stays true, you loop again and again. Like that

```
$con = true;

while($con) {
    if($con) {
        $con = your_function()
    }   
}

//your function
function your_function() {
    //do your stuff here
    if($file_upload_successful) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

At least i think this might work ... not even sure. Well, no risk no fun.

Comment: "no risk no fun" Brilliant!

Comment: I would prefer this usage over mine. Having a true/false return and abstracting the repeating to outside the function means the function itself is a lot more reusable. In addition, you could also use closures to build and make it even more powerful.

Comment: It looks great. However I thing I'm doing something wrong.
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function multiple_upload() in...` `multiple_upload` is how I named `your_function`. Note: I placed `$con` inside the `protected function _upload_file()` and put `protected function multiple_upload` after the `protected function _upload_file()`.

Comment: Hum. He doesnt know the function when hes inside the loop, so id say you cant call the `protected` function from there. The easiest solution would be to remove the `protected` if its not necessary. I dont know your code, so i cant give you that many advices.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `Y U NO WORK`'s answer is to use the function recursively.

E.g. if you had an array of files to upload..

```
function foo($array_of_files) {

    if(is_array($array_of_files) && count($array_of_files) > 0) {

        $file = array_shift($array_of_files);
        // ... Handle upload code.

        if(count($array_of_files) > 0) {

            foo($array_of_files);

        }

    }

}
```

However, this does build stack layers, and could be quite troublesome for debugging.

Using a while loop would be a sensible strategy so long as you handle the loop conditions correctly.